# xslt 1.0 substring-after to ignore case

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have 2 xml nodes like this, for example:

```
<Model>GRAND MODUS</Model>
<QualifiedDescription>2008 58 Reg Renault Grand Modus 1.2 TCE Dynamique 5drMetallic Flame Red</QualifiedDescription>
```

I'm trying to use substring-after to split the **QualifiedDescription** after the **Grand Modus** like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="something"><xsl:value-of select='substring-after(QualifiedDescription, Model)' /></xsl:variable>
```

But obviously it's not working being of it being case sensitive. Is it possible to get substring-after to work case insensitive, but still return the output with case preserved EG.

```
1.2 TCE Dynamique 5drMetallic Flame Red
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the two strings to the same case using `translate` in order to work out the character offset of the first within the second, then take a `substring` of the *original* `QualifiedDescription` from that position.

```
<xsl:variable name="uc" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="lc" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

<xsl:variable name="substrStart" select="
       string-length(substring-before(translate(QualifiedDescription, $uc, $lc),
                                      translate(Model, $uc, $lc)))
     + string-length(Model)
     + 1" /><!-- +1 because string indexes in XPath are 1-based -->

<xsl:variable name="something"
              select="substring(QualifiedDescription, $substrStart)" />
```

You'd need slightly more complex logic to take account of cases where the QualifiedDescription does not include the Model (since in this case both `substring-before` and `substring-after` return the empty string) but you get the idea.

Comment: Fantastic. Worked like a dream. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do case insensitive if you uppercase all first and substring on uppercase:

```
substring-after(upper-case(QualifiedDescription), upper-case(Model))
```

Comment: Hmmmmm. I'm getting upper-case()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Comment: `upper-case` is an XPath 2.0 function, it's not available in 1.0